# Show that a partial derivative exists in $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

$f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
xy \frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2} & ;(x,y)\neq(0,0) \\
0 & {; (x,y)=(0,0)} 
\end{cases}$

1. Show that all partial derivatives of $f$ exist everywhere and calculate these. Distinguish between $(x,y)=(0,0)$ and $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$.
2. Show that $D_1D_2f(0,0)$ and $D_2D_1f(0,0)$ exist but $D_1D_2f(0,0)\neq D_2D_1f(0,0)$.

---

1. $\frac{\delta}{\delta x}(xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2})=y(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{4x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2})$, $\frac{\delta}{\delta y}(xy\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2})=x(\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{4x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2})$

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: work with the definitions and it should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From definition we will have $f_x(0,0)=f_y(0,0)=0$. Using these we obtain:
$$f_{xy}(0,0) = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f_x(0,y)-f_x(0,0)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{-y^3}{y^3} = -1$$
$$f_{yx}(0,0) = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{f_y(x,0)-f_y(0,0)}{y} = \lim_{y \to 0}\frac{x^3}{x^3} = 1$$
It can be shown that in $(x,y) = (0,0)$ mixed partial derivatives have   discontinuity. Let's consider $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$
$$f_{xy}(x,y)=f_{yx}(x,y)=\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\left(1+\frac{8x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}   \right)$$
Now if we consider $(\frac{a}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$ then we obtain $\frac{a^2-1}{a^2+1}\left(1+\frac{8a^2}{(a^2+1)^2}   \right)$ for $(0,0)$

For $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$:
$$f_x(x,y)=y\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}+\frac{4x^2y^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$
$$f_y(x,y)=x\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}-\frac{4x^3y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$

Comment: Are you sure that this is correct? Another exercise is to prove that the function is continuous everywhere

Comment: @Lena67. I am speaking about  discontinuity of mixed partial derivatives in $(0,0)$ - would you like me add proof for it?

Comment: Ohhh ok, yes please :D

Comment: Done. Please, look at it.