# Show continuity of partial derivatives of piece-wise function

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

> Consider the $f:\mathbb{R}^2 \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$f(x,y) = \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $f(0,0)=0$. Show that f $\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2), f \not \in C^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

To show $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, I calculated that $\nabla f = <\frac{yx^4+4x^2y^3-y^5}{(x^2+y^2)^2},\frac{x^5-4x^3y^2-xy^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2}>$, which is obviously continuous for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, but at $(x,y) = (0,0)$, I don't think this function is of much use. I used the limit definition of partials to show the partials exists at $(0,0)$, but I'm lost as to how to show they are continuous here.

For the second derivative case, I am even more lost as to prove that the partials are not continuous at $(0,0)$, since I don't have a function representation of the partials at $(0,0)$ to prove continuity with.

Comment: Is this duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3748502/show-that-a-partial-derivitave-exists-in-0-0/3748525#3748525 ?

Comment: That's a great answer and helps, but still doesn't answer how to show $f \in C^1(\mathbb{R}^2)$. Particularly, how to show the first-derivative partials are discontinuous at $(0,0)$.

Comment: First derivatives are continuous everywhere - for $(0,0)$ added as answer. Would you like me add something more?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly calculate $f_x(0,0)$ by definition:
$$f_x(0,0)=\lim_\limits{x \to 0}\frac{f(x,0)-f(0,0)}{x} = 0$$
Let's proof, that $f_x$ is continuous in $(0,0)$:
$$|f_x(x,y)-f_x(0,0)| = \frac{|x^4y+4x^2y^3-y^5|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \leqslant \frac{6(x^2+y^2)^{5/2}}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = 6(x^2+y^2)^{1/2}$$

Comment: How did you derive the first inequality: $|x^4y + 4x^2y^3 - y^5| \leq 6(x^2 + y^2)^{5/2}$?

Comment: Simplifying gives proof, but I think you are asking about idea? Idea = estimating + not less power in right, then in left. Maybe. It's hard to explain how comes idea.

Comment: How did you simplify? Could you show how you found the inequality?

Comment: Take both sides in second power. On left side you'll have only even degrees.

Comment: This is not a proof of anything until you’ve proved that $f_x(0,0)=0$ and you’ve inserted that into your argument.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin. In OP is written, that partial derivatives in $(0,0)$ are already calculated. Anyway, added to answer.

Comment: Pedagogically, I'm suggesting saying explicitly that your estimate is on $|f_x(x,y)-f_x(0,0)|$.